# Oracle - insufficient privileges

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have created this user "user1" in order to create my own tables and triggers on them, because I think it's not a great idea to create tables and triggers as SYS (I got the exception that I can't create a trigger on a specific table created by SYS).

This "user1" has the following privileges:

```
create user user1 identified by password1;
grant connect to user1 ;
grant create session to user1 ;
grant resource to user1 ;
grant unlimited tablespace to user1 ;
grant all privileges to user1 ;
grant dba to user1 ;
```

But still, I can't connect to the database and I get a "insufficient privileges"-error when I try to login.

Which privilege(s) is(are) missing?

This is the output:

It's german and means:

```
-user1 created
-grant succeeded
-connected
-The established connection got closed with "Connected"-Script command
```

[image]

**And when I then try to login, I get the following error:**

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you didn't issue `create user "user1" identified by password1`, instead of `create user user1 identified by password1`?

Comment: would it be the correct way with apostrophes? Because I issued the command without them.

Comment: no, there's no problem with your commands, everything is OK and even more. I just wondered if you mistakenly issued `"user1"`, instead of `user1` at any step.

Comment: `resource` and `connect` are the old default roles, and are deprecated by Oracle. It is better to create your old roles or scripts to grant the appropriate set of privileges. In real life there are no circumstances in which it is appropriate to `grant all privileges`. However, **your statements as presented should work**, so whatever is happening is not what you think is happening. Please post actual output if you want us to help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boy, you granted all possible (and impossible) privileges :)

Believe or not, those - actually - work. Have a look what happens on my 11g XE:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create user user1 identified by password1;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create session to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant resource to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant unlimited tablespace to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant all privileges to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant dba to user1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect user1/password1@xe
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

See? Everything seems to be fine - I'm connected as USER1 and have created a table. Would you mind posting the same output as I did, but this time ran on YOUR database so that we could see what you did and how Oracle responded?

By the way, I'd suggest you not to do it the way you did: when creating users, grant only minimum set of privileges he needs. If it turns out that he needs something else, you can easily grant it. Granting DBA role to it is, huh, kind of *dangerous*. This is how I usually do that:

```
SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> drop user user1 cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS

SQL> create user user1 identified by password1
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  profile default
  5  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to user1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect user1/password1@xe
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see; what happens if you do NOT connect in SQL Developer's worksheet window, but - actually - create a brand new connection (you know, click the green "+" button and fill all required fields)?

Comment: And when I create a new connection (With the "+" button) and some tables I still can't create a trigger on a table which I created with "user1" due to an error which says "Cannot create triggers on object owned by SYS"

Comment: It is SQL Developer. Although it "acts" like SQL Plus in many ways, it is *not* SQL Plus so - CONNECT doesn't work as you'd expect it to.  As of the error while creating a trigger: are you *sure* you're now connected as USER1? What is the result of this: `select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE';`

Comment: Oh well, it works - I am sorry. There were so many errors and at the bottom it says "Trigger ___ compiled" so I didn't see it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166753/discussion-between-watchme-and-littlefoot).